# MapKit crashing after adding new authorization process

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, ios8, mkuserlocation

I am trying to get the Map Kit to display the current user's location down to a predefined size.

Everything was working but since updating to Xcode 6 and iOS 8, things have changed.

I have implemented the necessary authorizations and now the app crashes. The code with `***` is the code that the system seems to have a problem with.

Here is Map.m

```
#import "MRVCMapViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@import CoreLocation;

@interface MRVCMapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MRVCMapViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     //location permission

     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     self.locationManager.delegate = self;


    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //mapview settings

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation   *)userLocation
{
    ***MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate,   800, 800);
     [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];***
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Whenever saying "the app crashes", always include the exact crash message shown in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't checked that the `userLocation` value is valid. You should make sure it is not `nil` before trying to use it for anything.

Comment: Hi Craig the code minus the user permission worked fine before the update.

Comment: Did you try checking the userLocation is not nil? Maybe before it was able to get the location in time. Maybe under iOS 8 it takes longer to get the location and sends out the `nil` first. It's very easy to check and without any more detail from you about what the crash is it's the best I can suggest.